# How to make the table fill the entire horizontal space?

Tags: tables

I want the table to fit the available horizontal space. How to fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=1cm,landscape,includemp,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{helvet}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Huge\bfseries Mathematics and Physics Schedule
\end{center}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{25mm}|*5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr\dimexpr\textwidth-25mm\relax/5\relax}|}}\hline
Time & Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday \\\hline
16:00-16:30 &&&&&\\\hline
16:30-17:00 &&&&&\\\hline
17:00-17:30 &&&&&\\\hline
17:30-18:00 &&&&&\\\hline
18:00-18:30 &&&&&\\\hline
18:30-19:00 &&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `includemp=false` and define the tabular with the following.

```
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{25mm}|*5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr\dimexpr\textwidth-25mm-12\tabcolsep-7\arrayrulewidth\relax/5\relax}|}
```

Comment: I forgot this legacy trick.

Answer (score 2):

`\resizebox` is always an option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=1cm,landscape,includemp,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Huge\bfseries Mathematics and Physics Schedule
\end{center}

\noindent%
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{25mm}|*5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr\dimexpr\textwidth-25mm\relax/5\relax}|}}\hline
Time & Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday \\\hline
16:00-16:30 &&&&&\\\hline
16:30-17:00 &&&&&\\\hline
17:00-17:30 &&&&&\\\hline
17:30-18:00 &&&&&\\\hline
18:00-18:30 &&&&&\\\hline
18:30-19:00 &&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=1cm,landscape,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|m{25mm}|*5{X|}}\hline
Time & Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday \\\hline
16:00-16:30 &&&&&\\\hline
16:30-17:00 &&&&&\\\hline
17:00-17:30 &&&&&\\\hline
17:30-18:00 &&&&&\\\hline
18:00-18:30 &&&&&\\\hline
18:30-19:00 &&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```